# How do I use the required packages when converting to exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, auto-py-to-exe

I tried converting a .py file to .exe using auto-py-to-exe, but the packages arent included, and I get this error:

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "imgtoascii.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

How do I use the packages on the file?

--onefile mode, python 3.10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen)

Comment: @SurajShourie No, I use auto-py-to-exe, which is a program that just makes it easier to use pyinstaller. I just can't figure out how to include the necessary packages IN the exe file. Even when the executable is in the same directory as pip, it doesn't work.